# regex is counting only one pattern, when two same patterns are kept consecutive.why?

Tags: python, regex

The following is an input.

> INPUT
>   2
>   businessman video demeanor demeanor dishonest acknowledge dvd honor sister opportunity
>   keen labour artistic favourite red definition impatient take behaviour warmth
>   1
>   demeanour
>
> OUTPUT
>   2

Because here demeanour is converted to its US launguage equivalent 'demenor' and then the number of 'demeanour' and 'demeanor' have to be counted.

I wrote the following code but it outputs 1 instead of 2

```
import re
n = int(raw_input())
b = []
for i in range(n):
  b.append(raw_input())
b = " ".join(b)
b = b + " "
t = int(raw_input())
c = []
for i in range(t):
  c = raw_input()
  d = c[:-2]+"r"

  match = re.findall(r"\s"+re.escape(c)+"\s",b)
  match2 = re.findall(r"\s"+re.escape(d)+"\s",b)
  print len(match)+len(match2)
```

I may have not completely explained you the scenario to know more please visit,
https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/uk-and-us-2

PS: This is my first question on stackoverflow. Please correct me, if the problem is presented incorrectly.

EDIT:
Correct Answer:

```
import re
n = int(raw_input())
b = []
for i in range(n):
  b.append(raw_input())
b = " ".join(b)
b = b + " "
t = int(raw_input())

for i in range(t):
  c = raw_input()
  d = c.replace("ou","o")
  k = re.compile(r'\b%s\b'%c,re.I)
  l = re.compile(r'\b%s\b'%d,re.I)

  match = k.findall(b)
  match2 = l.findall(b)
  print len(match)+len(match2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Alternation](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) in your regex:

```
import re

input='''\
businessman video demeanor demeanour dishonest acknowledge dvd honor sister opportunity keen labour artistic favourite red definition impatient take behaviour warmth'''

matches=re.findall(r'(demeanour|demeanor)', input)   
print matches, len(matches) 
# ['demeanor', 'demeanour'] 2
```

Or, use a [optional quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html):

```
matches=re.findall(r'(demeanou?r)', input) 
print matches, len(matches)
```

To keep from matching `xyzdemeanour` use a [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html):

```
matches=re.findall(r'(\bdemeanou?r\b)', 'demeanor demeanour xyzdemeanour demeanourxyz') 
print matches, len(matches) 
# ['demeanor', 'demeanour'] 2
```

Comment: your answer may produce error because it may count xyzdemeanor or abxdemeanor also. we have to make sure that demeanor/demeanour is a single word and not a substring.Also we don't know what our input is user may ask something else other than 'demeanor'.
The above test case i just one of the many test cases.

Comment: I made it...Can't upload my answer here because my reputation is less than 10...but thank you...no need to bother any further...thanks again for your help. I used re.compiler('\b%s\b'%c,re.I) @dawg

Answer (score 0):

If all you have to consider is words like *odour -> odor* (missing the *u*), you can make something like:

```
import re

n = int(raw_input()) # Read number of lines
b = ""
for i in range(n): # Read lines and concatenate them to a string
  b += raw_input() + " " 
t = int(raw_input()) # Read number of words
c = []
for i in range(t): # Read words
  word = raw_input()
  c.append(word) # Add each word to a list
  c.append(word.replace("u","")) # Add also the word without the u to the list

totallen = 0 
for i in c: # Search for all words
  match = re.findall(r""+i+"\s",b) # find all occurrences of a word 
  totallen += len(match) # Add it to total count 

print totallen # Print total
```

I tested it on the website you write and it passed all the tests, but I will recommend you to write names for a variable that explain better what the are suppose to have, like `numberoflines`, `numberofwords`, `text`,`words`, etc

Comment: @RudenBermudez
The problem still remains..the test given on the site is a simpler.
Use a custom test case:
2
the odour odour coming out of the leftover food was intolerable
ammonia has a very pungent odor
1
odour
The output would come out as '2' instead of '3'
Please check.

Comment: In the sentence you wrote, there are 2 times *odour* and 1 time *odor*, so you want to count only the *odour* words or both? I understood it was both

Comment: Yes, I want to count both. but the when I run code it outputs 2 but it should output 3.
P.S. - Sorry for poor explanation.

Comment: I made it...Can't upload my answer here because my reputation is less than 10...but thank you...no need to bother any further...thanks again for your help. @Ruben

Comment: You can't post an answer, but you can update your question and add it there. It may be helpful for  someone in the future

Comment: Thanks...I have updated my question with 'EDIT' section.@Ruben